# Période entre l'obtention du diplôme et l'embauche

Tags: vocabulaire, questions

Une question qui se présente dans n'importe quel cadre professionnel : comment s'appelle la période entre la date d'obtention du diplôme et la date de premier emploi ? Est-ce qu'on l'appelle une période de chômage ?

Comment: Non locuteur natif mais je trouve pas cet emploi de chaumage dans le lemma du mot ici : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaumage

Comment: En Belgique, il existe un terme officiel: "stage d'insertion professionnelle" (appelé autrefois "stage d'attente" - terme un peu hypocrite puisqu'il ne s'agit pas d'un "stage" en entreprise ou autre). Mais cette période est légalement limitée dans le temps et correspond à un régime particulier pour les allocations de chômage. Lorsque cette limite de temps est passée, on parlera simplement de "chômage". Peut-être existe-t-il une terminologie officielle similaire en France et dans les autres pays francophones ? Un locuteur natif du "pays-cible" pourrait commenter...

Comment: @dimitris Tout le monde ne va pas ramasser la paille dans les champs après ses études... ;-)

Comment: @Greg > Le stage d'attente ne qualifie pas exactement cette période, mais bien la partie pendant laquelle tu ne touches pas d'allocation de chômage. Il s'agit simplement de dispositions légales, et le fait que cela change de nom au gré des différentes réformes semble plaider dans ce sens.

Comment: Parfois, le diplôme est obtenu en juin et la date de première embauche se situe en septembre. La période intercalaire est habituellement considérée comme des _vacances_.

Comment: Justement une période de repos, ou bien de vacance rien cas ce je pense que ca n'existe pas un terme plus significatif

Answer (score 3):

Carnelune fait justement observer la définition du mot.

Mais je doute qu'il corresponde précisément à ta situation tant, bien que sans *emploi salarié*, entre tes CV, tes rendez-vous, tes démarches administratives... tu n'es certainement pas à te tourner les pouces...

Par ailleurs, on observe de plus en plus employée la locution *droit au chômage* dans *avoir droit au chômage*, ou *ayant droit au chômage*, comme si *chômage* avait en fait absorbé le concept d' *allocation*.

Cet emploi dérivé ne correspond pas non plus à ta situation.

Je crois donc préférable de qualifier cette période de *recherche d'emploi* voire de *recherche de premier emploi*.

Comment: "entre tes CV, tes rendez-vous, tes démarches administratives... tu n'es certainement pas à te tourner les pouces..." c'est probablement une preuve de naïveté de ma part, mais je considère que toute personne au chômage (que ce soit ou non juste après l'obtention du diplôme) fait cela !

Comment: @Carnelune Oui Carnelune absolument. C'est aussi peut-être pourquoi le mot *chômage* tel qu'il me semble être employé aujoud'hui ne correspond plus rigoureusement à sa définition du dictionnaire. Un *chômeur* n'est plus vraiment *sans travail*, il est plus *sans emploi salarié*

Comment: Nos deux réponses se complètent. On peut être au chômage sans chercher d'emploi, être au chômage et en recherche d'emploi, ou encore avoir un emploi mais en chercher un autre ! +1 pour ton évocation de *recherche de premier emploi* qui me semble donc convenir le plus.

Answer (score 2):

Toute période sans emploi correspond au terme chômage :

> Situation d'une personne caractérisée par le manque de travail

Afin de spécifier le cas particulier de non-travail entre l'obtention d'un diplôme et la date de premier emploi, il est possible de parler de chômage post diplôme.

Comme relevé par dimitris dans les commentaires, chaumage a un sens différent de son paronyme :

> Action de retirer le chaume d'un champ ; le chaume étant ce qui reste de la tige des céréales après leur récolte.